# Probability of getting SUCCESS AND FAILURE at number n-1 and n trial

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, generating-functions

In a sequence of Bernoulli trials let $u_n$ be the probability that the combination SF occurs for the first time at the trials number n-1 and n. To find the generating function I wrote the following recurrence relation but need verification.
$$u_n=(1-u_{n-2})pq$$
I would much appreciate if someone could help me derive the generating function and verify the above recurrence relation.Thanks in advance

Comment: I fail to see where this recursion would come from. Can you explain?

Comment: Working out a few examples on paper, I'm getting $u_{2k} = \sum_{i=1}^k (-1)^{i+1} (pq)^i$. You should be able to prove this is correct by induction using your recurrence relation. Also, I think that $u_{2k} = u_{2k+1}$ for all $k$ (check this).

Comment: @did Since $(1-U_{n-2})$ is the probability of SF not occurring at all in n-2 trials $(1-U_{n-2})pq$ gives it happening at the nth. This was the logic behind mine.

Comment: @Did I edited my comment above

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like $(1-\sum_{k=2}^{n-2} u_k)pq$, then? And even like this, this would not be correct as this leaves out the possibility of SF occurring at position $(n-2,n-1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The combination SF appears for the first time at times $n-1$ and $n$ if and only if two conditions are met:

- Trials $n-1$ and $n$ are S and F.
- Trials from $1$ to $n-2$ are a sequence of $i$ trials F followed by $n-2-i$ trials S, for some $0\leqslant i\leqslant n-2$.

Hence,
$$
u_n=\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}q^ip^{n-i-1}q=qp^{n-1}\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}\left(\frac{q}p\right)^i=\ldots$$
**Edit:** A recursive formula which can be used to compute the sequence $(u_n)_{n\geqslant1}$ is that $u_1=0$ and, for every $n\geqslant0$,
$$
u_{n+2}=pq(1-U_{n}),\qquad U_n=\sum_{i=1}^nu_i.
$$

Comment: Thanks! if you don't mind can you explain where I went wrong in my recursive formula

Comment: You probably miscopied the book where you found the formula, see Edit.

Comment: Thanks but it was not copied from anywhere I just came up with it. I know where I went wrong now thanks again